# How to set fonts with multiple font files in LuaLatex

Tags: latex, fontspec

I am using ShareLatex as my online Latex editor. I want to use Times New Roman as my font but due to licence issues, ShareLatex can not distrubute this font. With the help of their [documentation page](https://tr.sharelatex.com/blog/2013/04/02/using-your-favourite-fonts-with-sharelatex.html) I added the following lines, uploaded the fonts and now its working.

```
\setmainfont[SmallCapsFeatures={Renderer=Basic},
Ligatures={TeX, NoCommon, NoDiscretionary}]{times.ttf}
```

But the problem is, bold and italic texts are just regular since I have pointed **times.ttf** only. Then I added **timesbd.ttf** with a comma and tried this:

```
\setmainfont[SmallCapsFeatures={Renderer=Basic},
Ligatures={TeX, NoCommon, NoDiscretionary}]{times.ttf, timesbd.ttf}
```

Now the tex file can not be compiled, I couldn't succeed. How can I overcome the issue? Note that I am using **LuaLatex** as compiler.

Comment: Try `\setmainfont[..]{times.tff}[BoldFont=timesbd.tff]`.

Comment: It worked, thanks.